# Rails 4: Change 'name' attribute of Simple Form input

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, simple-form

I am using Simple Form in a Rails 4 app for a `@user` object and have the line...

```
= f.input :entity_name
```

This generates the HTML `name='user[entity_name]'` inside the `input` tag. I would like to change it because of some custom processing I am doing in the controller but haven't found a way to do so.

I've tried changing the line to...

```
= f.input :entity_name, name: 'entity[name]'
```

...but this doesn't seem to affect the generated HTML at all. So far I haven't found anyone else with this question on Google/Stack Overflow.

Does anyone know if/how it's possible to change the name attribute through the Simple Form helper?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The trick is using the `input_html` option.

```
= f.input :entity_name, input_html: { name: 'entity[name]' }
```

Answer (score -4):

If you're looking to just change the shown label of the field:

```
= f.input :entity_name, label: 'new_input_field_name'
```